# Specify association type when reverse engineering java

Tags: enterprise-architect

My model of using Enterprise Architect is to define model classes in Java and then reverse engineer them in EA. This allows me to keep issues of my model as TODO comments and also to define ENumeration classes using a consistent pattern.

When I reverse engineer the java package containing my model I get a decent UML class diagram (good). But I am looking for ways to specify within my java code the type of each relationship (association / aggregation / composition). Is there some way I can do that? For example does EA support infering relationship type based on a comment or annotation style?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the two approaches
1. Use an add-in to modify the relationships (set type, stereotype, etc) based on the imported comments
2. Use Model transformation to transform your imported model based on the comments (may be slightly trickier)